# Force Jupyter Notebook *not* to open a web browser

Tags: python, ssh, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, python-webbrowser

I'm running Jupyter notebooks (Python 3) on a remote cluster that I'm connected/tunneled to over SSH.

Jupyter's default behavior is to try to open the dashboard in a web browser when it launches -- aparently (I only just updated), at some point they switched to the Python 3 [`webbrowser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html) library for this.

According to `webbrowser`'s documentation:

> text-mode browsers will be used if graphical browsers are not available or an X11 display isn’t available.

This is exactly what happens. I run `jupyter notebook`, `webbrowser` launches `elinks`, and my one-time authentication token gets eaten, preventing me from connecting to the notebook.

Jupyter isn't configured to use a browser -- `c.NotebookApp.browser` is commented out in my config -- and running `BROWSER="" jupyter notebook` doesn't help either.

How can I force Jupyter *not* to open any browser?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

Then edit `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` and Add

```
NotebookApp.open_browser = False
```

Answer (score 34):

`jupyter-notebook --help` includes the following:

```
--no-browser
    Don't open the notebook in a browser after startup.
```

Comment: Thank you. I was in the help page, don't know how I missed this.

Comment: thankyou ... i am searching for this feature

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve this by specifying --no-browser:

```
$ jupyter notebook --no-browser
```

I also recommend that you specify the port you want to use:

`jupyter notebook --no-browser --port= <port_number>`

ie:

```
$ jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8888
```

You have to keep in mind that when you do this, jupyter will provide you with a token on the console, token that the server will ask you when connect remotely through the browser.

If you want to simplify this procedure, you can set a password that is easier for you to remember. To do this, you can run in a console:

```
$ jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

and later:

```
$ jupyter notebook password
```

This last command will ask you for the password that you wish to use to enter remotely.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `jupyter lab` or other jupyter tooling, the browser might still open.

**To always disable the browser for all jupyter commands**, edit your default config at:

```bash
~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

And add the following lines:

```py
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
c.LabApp.open_browser = False
c.ServerApp.open_browser = False
c.ExtensionApp.open_browser = False
```

---

Source:

> From Jupyter help pages:
>
> ```
> --no-browser
>     Prevent the opening of the default url in the browser.
>     Equivalent to: [--ServerApp.open_browser=False --ExtensionApp.open_browser=False]
> ```